# local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect with the snowflake database, but it says local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment. Am I missing something in the code?

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
def Source_database(self, source):

        try:
            print('######################################Cursor creation on database#################################')
              if source['systemType'] == 'mysql':
         '''block of code'''
        exception: 
             print("")
              elif source['systemType'] == 'snowflake':
      
                 try:

                   snowflake_connection = None
                   source_db_name = 'xxx'
                   source_db_username = 'xxx'
                   source_db_password = 'xxx'
                   source_db_port = 'xx'
                   source_db_endpoint = 'xxx'
                   source_db_warehouse = 'xx'
                   schema_name = 'xx'
                   with closing(sf.connect()) as conn:
                        with closing(conn.cursor()) as cursor:
                            snowflake_connection = sf.connect(user=source_db_username,password=source_db_password,
                                                            warehouse=source_db_warehouse, database=source_db_name,schema=schema_name,
                                                            account= source_db_endpoint)
                            print('Success')
                            #cursor = snowflake_connection.cursor()
                            self.engine = snowflake_connection
                            print("Snowflake Cursor created Successfully")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Snowflake Cursor is not built please check the connection details {}".format(e))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Where is your `sf` variable being initialized? I can't see where that is happening.

Comment: @SimonD Thanks for your comment. I resolved this. The root cause for this issue is the endpoint where I need not have to specify the domain name but in the main code, I have passed with the domain name. Snowflake will append the domain name for the endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for this issue is the endpoint where I need not have to specify the domain name for the snowflake database. But in the main code, I have passed with the domain name and Snowflake will also try to append the domain name for the endpoint. This issue is resolved. Thanks, everyone for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, connection class doesn't have cursor member

```py
elif source['systemType'] == 'snowflake':
                try:
                    snowflake_connection = None
                    source_db_name = 'xxx'
                    source_db_username = 'xxx'
                    source_db_password = 'xxx'
                    source_db_port = 'xx'
                    source_db_endpoint = 'xxx'
                    source_db_warehouse = 'xx'
                    schema_name = 'xx'
                    with closing(sf.connect()) as conn:
                        with closing(sf.cursor()) as cursor:
                            snowflake_connection = sf.connect(user=source_db_username,password=source_db_password,
                                                            warehouse=source_db_warehouse, database=source_db_name,schema=schema_name,
                                                            account= source_db_endpoint)
                            print('Success')
                            #cursor = snowflake_connection.cursor()
                            self.engine = snowflake_connection
                            print("Snowflake Cursor created Successfully")
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Snowflake Cursor is not built please check the connection details {}".format(e))
```

Try this

Comment: Trying the above code I get the error as "Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Comment: What is the function. Can you include it in your code?